# flex value objects with database

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript

I know this question is vague, but I have a school project, which works with HttpServices that call to PHP-files to insert and retrieve data from a database. Now the teacher told me I have to work with valueObjects to work with the database, but I haven't received any further information. I can't figure out what to do...

Comment: Well, if the problem is you don't know what a ValueObject is, you could begin by searching (or asking) what it is.

Comment: Has the teacher told you whether the services exist, or are you expected to write them?

Comment: Is that the same teacher from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851875/looping-over-elements-inside-an-element-in-flex/7851976)? I'd be happy to replace him if it were just a bit closer to Brussels ;-b

Comment: @RIAstar Exactly, it's the same person, it's a woman. She gives some other subjects, which she has the same lack of knowledge. Frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

I have a good sample app and tutorial for using Flex and PHP for database connectivity using valueObjects and zend-amf as the server on my blog, which should be a good starting (and maybe finishing point). The example has View Source enabled, and I have included all the php files that were used. I expect a good +1 for this:-)

http://bbishop.org/blog/?p=441

Answer (score 0):

You should find a lot of information in the [Flex In a Week](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/videotraining.html#day3) video series on Adobe TV.

Probably the answer to all your questions and more.